# Unable to ping github in AWS IPv6-only EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, vpc

I'm unable to ping many websites in my Amazon AWS EC2 instance, including github. It's an IPv6-only instance, and includes an internet gateway and a routing table that associates with that gateway. The routing table includes a route to the internet gateway.

Whenever I ping github.com, I get `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`. I am able to ping google.com from that instance. For my default VPC (ipv4), I'm able to ping github just fine from EC2 instances. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you provide the routes configured in your routing table?

Comment: Other than the local routes, I have ::/0 -> igw-069c525c32aeade3e (my internet gateway).

Comment: Local routes are 2600:1f16:a91:4f00::/56->local and 172.31.0.0/16->local

Comment: To eliminate more possibilities, could you try issuing "telnet github.com 443"?

Comment: I get `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPv4 clients can’t talk to it directly to a IPv6 only Server.
Google has IPv6 configured for their website but github.com does not. (But as I understand it they are close to suport it now)